# i want to get the currency by using option value

Tags: javascript

```js
const currencyone = document.querySelector(".currency-one");
const currenciesone = currencyone.querySelectorAll("option");
const currencytwo = document.querySelector(".currency-two");
const currenciestwo = currencytwo.querySelectorAll("option");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const amountone = document.querySelector("#amount-one");

button.addEventListener("click", get);

async function get() {
  var response = await fetch(
    `https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/c1840f1544632103eddeafff/latest/USD`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  for (i = 0; i < currenciesone.length; i++) {
    if (currenciesone[i].selected) {
      let value = currenciesone[i].value;
      console.log(data.conversion_rates.value);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(29, 187, 127);
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(29, 187, 127);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  outline: none;
}

.money-img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.currency select {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%20000002%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-position: right 10px top 50%, 0, 0;
  background-size: 12px auto, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.currency input {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: rgb(29, 187, 127);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

select:focus,
input:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="money.png" alt="" class="money-img" />
    <h1>Exchange Rate Calculator</h1>
    <p>Choose the currency and the amounts to get the exchange rate</p>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="currency">
            <select class="currency-one">
                <option value="AED">AED</option>
                <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
                <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
                <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
                <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
                <option value="BSD">BSD</option>
                <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                <option value="CLP">CLP</option>
                <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
                <option value="COP">COP</option>
                <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
                <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
                <option value="DOP">DOP</option>
                <option value="EGP">EGP</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                <option value="FJD">FJD</option>
                <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                <option value="GTQ">GTQ</option>
                <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
                <option value="HRK">HRK</option>
                <option value="HUF">HUF</option>
                <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
                <option value="ILS">ILS</option>
                <option value="INR">INR</option>
                <option value="ISK">ISK</option>
                <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
                <option value="KRW">KRW</option>
                <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
                <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
                <option value="MYR">MYR</option>
                <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
                <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
                <option value="PAB">PAB</option>
                <option value="PEN">PEN</option>
                <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
                <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
                <option value="PLN">PLN</option>
                <option value="PYG">PYG</option>
                <option value="RON">RON</option>
                <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
                <option value="SAR">SAR</option>
                <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                <option value="SGD">SGD</option>
                <option value="THB">THB</option>
                <option value="TRY">TRY</option>
                <option value="TWD">TWD</option>
                <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
                <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
                <option value="UYU">UYU</option>
                <option value="VND">VND</option>
                <option value="ZAR">ZAR</option>
            </select>
            <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="0" value="1" />
        </div>

        <div class="swap-rate-container">
            <button class="btn" id="swap">
                Swap
            </button>
            <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="currency">
            <select class="currency-two">
                <option value="AED">AED</option>
                <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
                <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
                <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
                <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
                <option value="BSD">BSD</option>
                <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                <option value="CLP">CLP</option>
                <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
                <option value="COP">COP</option>
                <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
                <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
                <option value="DOP">DOP</option>
                <option value="EGP">EGP</option>
                <option value="EUR" selected>EUR</option>
                <option value="FJD">FJD</option>
                <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                <option value="GTQ">GTQ</option>
                <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
                <option value="HRK">HRK</option>
                <option value="HUF">HUF</option>
                <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
                <option value="ILS">ILS</option>
                <option value="INR">INR</option>
                <option value="ISK">ISK</option>
                <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
                <option value="KRW">KRW</option>
                <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
                <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
                <option value="MYR">MYR</option>
                <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
                <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
                <option value="PAB">PAB</option>
                <option value="PEN">PEN</option>
                <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
                <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
                <option value="PLN">PLN</option>
                <option value="PYG">PYG</option>
                <option value="RON">RON</option>
                <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
                <option value="SAR">SAR</option>
                <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                <option value="SGD">SGD</option>
                <option value="THB">THB</option>
                <option value="TRY">TRY</option>
                <option value="TWD">TWD</option>
                <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
                <option value="USD">USD</option>
                <option value="UYU">UYU</option>
                <option value="VND">VND</option>
                <option value="ZAR">ZAR</option>
            </select>
            <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="0" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it is  `console.log(data.conversion_rates[value]);` it's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score 0):

hello i want to get the currency price by using option select value of json data but that didn't work ( i have to get the price of currency name when i select it there is data.conversion_rates on that is 52 currency i want to get the currency price when i select a currency option so i chose data.conversion_rates.value the value is a string of currency

Comment: please do not post this as an answer, edit your question and add it there

Comment: This is not an answer  for the question please try editing your question